# Adding one variable causes model to have "perfect fit"

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I am running a linear regression in R to see whether a significant relationship exists between any of my variables and the outcome, Z. It appears that none of my variables have a significant relationship with this outcome... until I add the variable called "binary." Suddenly, many variables are wildly significant. My question is: why would adding a single variable change the output so drastically?

The dataframe I'm using is below:

```
sample <- data.frame(
            Z = c(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 
               -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5),
            v1 = c(23, 25, 42, 52, 38, 34, 57, 48, 29, 49, 
                       31, 45, 31, 30, 29, 28, 41, 45, NA, NA, 31), 
            v2 = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No","No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                               "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
             v3 = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                                    "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                                     "No", "No", "No"), 
            mar_status.factor = c(NA, NA, "Never Married", "Married", 
                                    "Never Married", "Never Married", "Never Married", "Married", 
                                    "Never Married", "Never Married", "Never Married", NA, 
                                    "Never Married", "Never Married", "Never Married", "Never Married", 
                                    "Never Married", "Separated", NA, NA, "Never Married"), 
             highest_ed.factor = c(NA, NA, "Did not complete high school", "Associates Degree", 
               "Regular high school diploma", "Some college credit, but less than 1 year", 
               "GED or equivalent", "Some college credit, but less than 1 year", 
               "Regular high school diploma", "Did not complete high school", 
               "Did not complete high school", NA, "Bachelors Degree", 
               "Did not complete high school", "Did not complete high school", 
               "Did not complete high school", "Bachelors Degree", 
               "GED or equivalent", NA, NA, "Did not complete high school"), 
             v4 = c(NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, NA, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, NA, 3, 2, 
               1, 3, 3, 1, NA, NA, 1), 
              v5= c(NA, NA, 27600, 15000, 1400, NA, 600, 10800, NA, 12000, NA, NA, 9000, 3000, 
                            2100, 13000, 60000, 10000, NA, NA, 0), 
            binary = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1))
```

When I run the below model in R, I get the accompanying output, which is completely insignificant.

```
Call:
lm(formula = Z ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + mar_status.factor + highest_ed.factor + 
    v4 + v5, data = sample)

Residuals:
         3          4          5          7          8         10         13         14         15         16         17         18 
 2.682e-01  1.596e-16  9.714e-17 -3.469e-17  6.939e-18 -1.040e-01  1.162e-01 -6.675e-01  1.162e-01  1.175e-01 -1.162e-01  2.082e-17 
        21 
 2.696e-01 

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
                                                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                                                 2.986e+00  2.662e+00   1.122    0.379
v1                                                         -4.539e-02  3.908e-02  -1.161    0.365
v2Yes                                                      -3.502e-02  1.207e+00  -0.029    0.979
v3Yes                                                      -7.087e-03  8.727e-01  -0.008    0.994
mar_status.factorNever Married                             -1.184e+00  9.049e-01  -1.308    0.321
mar_status.factorSeparated                                 -1.249e+00  1.656e+00  -0.754    0.530
highest_ed.factorBachelors Degree                          -6.862e-01  9.950e-01  -0.690    0.562
highest_ed.factorDid not complete high school               4.343e-02  8.932e-01   0.049    0.966
highest_ed.factorGED or equivalent                          6.811e-01  1.085e+00   0.628    0.594
highest_ed.factorRegular high school diploma                       NA         NA      NA       NA
highest_ed.factorSome college credit, but less than 1 year         NA         NA      NA       NA
v4                                                         -2.079e-01  4.975e-01  -0.418    0.717
v5                                                          3.320e-05  2.812e-05   1.181    0.359

Residual standard error: 0.5724 on 2 degrees of freedom
  (8 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.787, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.2779 
F-statistic: 0.739 on 10 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.6981
```

However, when I add one variable--called "binary" here--the output changes and tells me I have an "essentially perfect fit." Now, suddenly, several variables are very significant!

```
Call:
lm(formula = Z ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + mar_status.factor + highest_ed.factor + 
    v4 + v5 + binary, data = sample)

Residuals:
         3          4          5          7          8         10         13         14         15         16         17         18 
-1.414e-16 -8.628e-32 -4.314e-32  3.081e-32 -1.233e-32  8.539e-17 -2.853e-17 -5.686e-17 -2.853e-17  1.271e-16  2.853e-17 -6.163e-33 
        21 
 1.427e-17 

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
                                                             Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                                -5.000e-01  1.407e-15 -3.553e+14 1.79e-15 ***
v1                                                         -3.208e-17  1.962e-17 -1.635e+00    0.349    
v2Yes                                                      -1.000e+00  5.380e-16 -1.859e+15 3.42e-16 ***
v3Yes                                                       1.000e+00  4.369e-16  2.289e+15 2.78e-16 ***
mar_status.factorNever Married                             -1.000e+00  3.546e-16 -2.820e+15 2.26e-16 ***
mar_status.factorSeparated                                 -1.279e-15  7.279e-16 -1.758e+00    0.329    
highest_ed.factorBachelors Degree                          -4.737e-16  4.294e-16 -1.103e+00    0.469    
highest_ed.factorDid not complete high school               1.000e+00  4.346e-16  2.301e+15 2.77e-16 ***
highest_ed.factorGED or equivalent                          3.286e-16  4.605e-16  7.140e-01    0.605    
highest_ed.factorRegular high school diploma                       NA         NA         NA       NA    
highest_ed.factorSome college credit, but less than 1 year         NA         NA         NA       NA    
v4                                                         -3.218e-16  2.012e-16 -1.599e+00    0.356    
v5                                                          2.182e-20  1.421e-20  1.535e+00    0.368    
binary                                                      1.000e+00  2.743e-16  3.646e+15  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.22e-16 on 1 degrees of freedom
  (8 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 5.673e+30 on 11 and 1 DF,  p-value: 3.275e-16

Warning message:
In summary.lm(lm(Z ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + mar_status.factor + highest_ed.factor +  :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

**Why would adding this single variable change the output so drastically?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
m1 <- lm(formula = Z ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + mar_status.factor + highest_ed.factor + 
    v4 + v5, data = sample)
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . + binary)
```

You have 21 data points (`nrow(sample)`), but only 13 once observations with missing values in the response or any predictor variables are discarded (R does *complete case* analysis) (`nobs(m1)`). In the first model you have 11 independent parameters (`length(na.omit(coef(m1)))`, in the second you have 12. That leaves two residual degrees of freedom (`df.residual(m1)`) for model 1, only 1 for model 2, so you go from having a nearly perfect model to a perfect model.

You won't always get a perfect model this way (you would need **zero** residual df, not 1), but since you have only two distinct values in your response variable (-0.5 and 0.5), it's not surprising that you would be able to fit the data perfectly with 12 coefficients for 13 observations ...

And note that R **gave you a warning message**

> essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

which tells you *exactly* that the calculations that R uses break down in this case ...